# CSS: Half of my button disappears in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

As the title says; the lower half of my button disappears in IE7, and I can't figure out what causes this behavior.

HTML:

```
<button class="search-button button" type="submit">
    <span>
        <span>Sök</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button.button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E04E00;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}

button {
    font: 12px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the line-height of the parent element.

Comment: How about vertical-align:middle on the parent, too?